# How to add a border to the last angular components (list-group-item) generated with *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list of nested component generated in a *ngFor loop.
The hierarchy is : 
*ngFor categories of products -> *ngFor list of products
The item components have a 1px border, which turns into 2px when there is two close to each other.
I removed the bottom border for all the elements, but i can't manage to getan additional bottom border for the last component. This is what i have so far :

[image]

Here is the loop who generate my categories :

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <app-product-category
      *ngFor="let groupOfProduct of productGroups | keyvalue"
      [category]="groupOfProduct.key"
      [products]="groupOfProduct.value">
    </app-product-category>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the loop who generate the items inside the app-product-category component :

```html
<div class="collapse mb-2" id="collapseProducts{{category}}">
  <app-product-item
    *ngFor="let product of products; index as i; last as isLast"
    [product]="product"
    [index]="i"
    [ngClass]="{'last-child' : isLast}">
  </app-product-item>
</div>
```

And the css:

```css
.list-group-item {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.last-child>.list-group-item{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

The last component  get the good class, but the border doesn't display. Any idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you try the `:last-child`? `app-product-category > div:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid black;  }`

Comment: I found a way with the last stat from *ngFor. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[With `ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) you can get access to whether you're on the `last` element with.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; last as isLast">
  <p *ngIf="isLast"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello i'm not sure what exactly you're looking for but if you are trying to add a border then its not working then try changing the second part of you css from
this:

```
.last-child>.list-group-item{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
```

to this:

```
.last-child.list-group-item{
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code isn't working because your css selector is wrong. it should just be `.last-child .list-group-item` for a class descendant style.

but, if you want, you can get rid of the `last-child` class and not worry about the `ngFor` variable, and just use the css `:last-child` pseudo selector:

```
.list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

which will just apply the styles to the last matching element in a given group of sibling elements. 
 this is preferable for a number of reasons, most importantly though that if you reuse the `list-group-item` class in other lists, you won't have to replicate the `ngFor` template logic to apply the class everywhere you want this styling.

more on the selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: That's what i thought, and it's what i did first, but i don't know why, if i do ``.list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}`` it adds the bottom border to each div that has the class list-group-item, and so i have a 2px border for all the middles components

Comment: ah it's because they're wrapped in `app-product-item` so they're all a last child among their siblings... if you did `app-product-item:last-child` it would work.

Comment: I tried this too, but it doesn't work. I found a way by passing the isLast var to my app-product-item.ts, and i added a ``[ngClass]="{'last-child': lastChild}"`` to the list-group-items. Thanks a lot anyway !

Comment: it's not a scalable strategy. wouldn't recommend. better to figure out where you're going wrong with the css.

Comment: what do you mean by it's not scalable ? I just started Angular, so i guess i'm not having thee best practices yet !

Comment: I mean, if this is a class you intend to reuse, the need to repeat the class logic everywhere you use it is not a scalable approach to programming as you need to repeat and maintain in many places... css is scalable as you only need to do it once in one place